# Wordpress title reverse

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently using last version of wordpress.
For now my titles like this:

```
Home page -> SiteName - Just another wp site
Books -> Books - SiteName
Contacts -> Contact - SiteName
```

The question is how to reverse title tag using function.php filter?
I need:
Books - SiteName to be changed to SiteName - Books

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a plugin like Yoast for SEO?

Comment: I dont use Yoast. Just want to make reverse through the apply_filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse it by using **document_title_parts** filter

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'reverse_title_on_page');
function reverse_title_on_page($title)
{
    if (is_page() && !is_front_page()) { // check what you need
        $title = array_reverse($title);
    }
    return $title;
}
```